# Index.php file is missing in localhost while url is redirecting?

Tags: php, redirect

we have a website. while am running it in my local host, for every redirected url there is missing index.php file. if i put the index.php file in redirected url its working fine. but if i click on any other tabs/widgets again getting the same problem and every time i have to add this index file in url. when i launch my website using [http://localhost/zimplee/trunk/index.php](https://www.zimplee.com/index.php/) url, it will open the home page fine. after clicking on login tab url will redirect to [http://localhost/zimplee/trunk/customer/account/create/](https://www.zimplee.com/index.php/customer/account/login/). what is the problem i couldn't find it. please help me

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: is There index.php file in create folder?

Comment: yes.... i have index.php file in my root folder

Answer (score 0):

If on Apache, probably you didn't provide `DirectoryIndex` setting in apache's config file (Usually, httpd.conf). Insert this into it:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```

You can delete `index.html` if you don't need static files to be used for output.

You can read about `DirectoryIndex` in [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html)